# How do I read from memory.pressure_level in a cgroup?

Tags: linux, command-line, cgroups

I want to see the memory pressure of the cgroup. But simple `cat memory.presure_level` fails.

How do I know the current memory pressure of a cgroup?

Answer (score 3):

`memory.presure_level` is for receiving events, not for showing the level.

You can get idea about current memory pressure by comparing `memory.usage_in_bytes` with `memory.limit_in_bytes` and `memory.soft_limit_in_bytes`.

For looking for what happens in actual `memory.presure_level` I have developed a simple tool: https://gist.github.com/vi/46f921db3cc24430f8d4. It prints numbers each time the event is triggered.

```
# cgroup_memory_pressure_monitor low .
1
1
1
^C
```